# How to manipulate a nested dictionary and append a key to it in python?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary which is a default dict. I want to append a key to the nested dict by iterating through a list.
Not: new_dict is a default dict which was defined like this `new_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))`

```
from collections import defaultdict
new_dict = {'A': {'10.xxx.77.1': [7], '10.xxx.77.2': [8]}, 'B': {'10.xxx.77.1': [5], '10.xxx.77.2': [6]}}
positions = ['left','right']
for position in positions:
    for k, v in new_dict.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            v[position].extend(v)
print(new_dict)
```

> Actual output : {'A': {'10.xxx.77.1': [5], '10.xxx.77.2': [6], 'left': ['10.xxx.77.1', '10.xxx.77.2', 'left'], 'right': ['10.xxx.77.1', '10.xxx.77.2', 'left', 'right']}, 'B': {'10.xxx.77.1': [7], '10.xxx.77.2': [8], 'left': ['10.xxx.77.1', '10.xxx.77.2', 'left'], 'right': ['10.xxx.77.1', '10.xxx.77.2', 'left', 'right']}}
> {'A': {'10.xxx.77.1': [5], '10.xxx.77.2': [6], 'left': ['10.xxx.77.1', '10.xxx.77.2', 'left'], 'right': ['10.xxx.77.1', '10.xxx.77.2', 'left', 'right']}, 'B': {'10.xxx.77.1': [7], '10.xxx.77.2': [8], 'left': ['10.xxx.77.1', '10.xxx.77.2', 'left'], 'right': ['10.xxx.77.1', '10.xxx.77.2', 'left', 'right']}}

> Expected output `{'A': {'left': { '10.xxx.77.1', [5]},'right': {'10.xxx.77.2', [6]}},'B': {'left': {'10.xxx.77.1', [7]},'right': {'10.xxx.77.2', [8]}}}`

Comment: please check Expected output, it should be `{'A': {'10.xxx.77.1': [5], '10.xxx.77.2': [6]}, 'B': {'10.xxx.77.1': [7], '10.xxx.77.2': [8]}}`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want tuple as values:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
new_dict = {'A': {'10.xxx.77.1': [7], '10.xxx.77.2': [8]}, 'B': {'10.xxx.77.1': [5], '10.xxx.77.2': [6]}}
positions = ['left','right']

for k, v in new_dict.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
      new_dict[k] = {positions[0]:tuple(list(new_dict[k].items())[0]), positions[1]:tuple(list(new_dict[k].items())[1])}

print(new_dict)
```

Output as tuple of values:

```
{'A': {'left': ('10.xxx.77.1', [7]), 'right': ('10.xxx.77.2', [8])}, 'B': {'left': ('10.xxx.77.1', [5]), 'right': ('10.xxx.77.2', [6])}}
```

If you want dictionary as values:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
new_dict = {'A': {'10.xxx.77.1': [7], '10.xxx.77.2': [8]}, 'B': {'10.xxx.77.1': [5], '10.xxx.77.2': [6]}}
positions = ['left','right']

for k, v in new_dict.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
      new_dict[k] = {positions[0]:{tuple(list(new_dict[k].items())[0])[0]:tuple(list(new_dict[k].items())[0])[1]}, positions[1]:{tuple(list(new_dict[k].items())[1])[0]:tuple(list(new_dict[k].items())[1])[1]}}

print(new_dict)
```

Output as dictionary of values:

```
{'A': {'left': {'10.xxx.77.1': [7]}, 'right': {'10.xxx.77.2': [8]}}, 'B': {'left': {'10.xxx.77.1': [5]}, 'right': {'10.xxx.77.2': [6]}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the expected output, but it's depends on the order of the returned sequence by `new_dict[k].items()`, which is not always the one you want. In order to ensure the correctness you should sort it via `sorted` function, so the left mean left and the right means right, but it is not clear from your question what those suppose to mean.

```
from collections import defaultdict
new_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
new_dict.update({'A': {'10.xxx.77.1': [7], '10.xxx.77.2': [8]}, 'B': {'10.xxx.77.1': [5], '10.xxx.77.2': [6]}})
positions = ['left','right']

for k, v in new_dict.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        new_dict[k] = {pos: {key: val} for pos, (key, val) in zip(positions, new_dict[k].items())}

print(dict(new_dict))
```

Result:

> {'A': {'left': {'10.xxx.77.1': [7]}, 'right': {'10.xxx.77.2': [8]}},
> 'B': {'left': {'10.xxx.77.1': [5]}, 'right': {'10.xxx.77.2': [6]}}}